# Why am I getting the error "There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons"

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I installed an Extension, logged in admin panel. But if I press on the tab of the extension I get error like this:

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 673618173351

I went to var/report and opened the file with the Error log record number name: Deleted info

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

check in your database if `pixelsp0_mage318.productssold` table is present or not. table is not there as per the error which you posted....

if it is not their, then check core_resource if your script record is their or not.

If you don't get any record for your script then check for errors in your sql script.

if you find the record but version are not matching then either delete that record from this table so that your script will re execute and create a table or update the version of your script accordingly.

Also you can check these links which have solutions for similar issue :

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59300/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-shopstel-magento-core

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111786/sqlstate42s02-base-table-or-view-not-found-1146

Answer (score 0):

This is a general error that happens when InnoDB cannot write to its data files.

I've seen reports of this when the disk is full, or if permissions on the files changed so you can't write to them.

Another report was when someone enabled innodb_force_recovery to a value greater than 0, not realizing that in recovery modes >0, InnoDB is effectively read-only.